# FixedWidth binary columns in FlatFile Connection generated with BIML gets OutputColumnWidth at 0 (zero)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, biml

When I preview my BIML, this is how my columns are defined:

```
    <FlatFileFormat Name="(FFF) MyFixedWidthFlatFile" CodePage="1252" FlatFileType="FixedWidth" RowDelimiter="" IsUnicode="false" TextQualifier="_x003C_none_x003E_">
  <Columns>
    <Column Name="HEADER" DataType="Binary" Length="2" Delimiter="" TextQualified="false" ColumnType="FixedWidth" MaximumWidth="2"></Column>
    <Column Name="DESCRIPT" DataType="AnsiString" Length="30" Delimiter="" TextQualified="false" ColumnType="FixedWidth" MaximumWidth="30"></Column>
```

The package is generated succesfully, however, the OutputColumnWidth in the Flat File Connection is not set for the binary columns.

[image: Flat File Connection properties]

The String columns are correct.

[image]

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it work? I see the input column width picked up the 2 from your definition. Curiously enough, if I use that as an flat file input, the package will default(?) to a length of 255 in the metadata. I'll keep tab open as I go about work today and see if anything leaps out at me but my reproduction shows the same on the connection manager

Comment: Does it work? It does generate my package. But Vsual Studio warns me that there are errors loading it. Like I said, in the Flat File Connection Manager, the OutputColumnWidth for the binary columns is at zero, If I open the Flat File Source, I have a warning offering me to replace the metadata from the output columns with the ones from the external columns, If I do that, the binary columns in my Flat File Source default to 255. I can always edit each package one by one to correct that but that kind of defeats the purpose of BIML.

Comment: The MaximumWidth attribute is not created in the package for binary columns, so I guess I will have to write some code to parse the DTSX and add it that way. It's a shame BIML skips it.  :( Anyway, thanks for your time! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Might be worth an email to support at varigence.com or raise an issue on their github https://github.com/varigence/BimlPit/issues

Comment: I created an issue on their GitHub: https://github.com/varigence/BimlPit/issues/156

Answer (score 0):

So I did a thing.
The following code edits the DTSX file to add the missing attributes.
BEWARE: if you intend to reuse this code, it will change your package on save, not on package generation. If you're not comfortable with that, wrap it inside an EXE. Also, it could break your package so be sure you can generate it again or that you have a backup.
The package and the BIML file should be in the same directory.

```
<#@ template tier="999" language="VB" optionexplicit="False" #>
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#
Dim filename as string = "package.dtsx"
Dim packageFile As New XmlDocument()
packageFile.Load(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.templateFile) & "\" & filename)
Dim nodes as XmlNodeList = packageFile.GetElementsByTagName("DTS:FlatFileColumn")
If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
    For each node in nodes
        If node.Attributes("DTS:DataType").Value = "128"Then
            If node.Attributes("DTS:MaximumWidth") Is Nothing Then
                Dim mw as XmlAttribute = packageFile.CreateAttribute("MaximumWidth","www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts")
                mw.Value = node.Attributes("DTS:ColumnWidth").Value
                node.Attributes.InsertAfter(mw,node.Attributes("DTS:ColumnWidth"))
                #>
                <<#="Node " & node.Attributes("DTS:ObjectName").Value & " has changed."#>/>
                <#
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
packageFile.Save(Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.templateFile) & "\" & filename)
#>
</Biml>
```